# can't figure out how to do i18n on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, devise

in my rails3 app, i'm using devise for authentication

now i'm trying to do i18n. for that i saw a `devise.en.yml` in `config/locales`, and thought all i got to do is make an `devise.ro.yml` to translate it in my other language. but if the `devise.ro.yml` is present, everything is in ro, no matter the language i use

for changing language, i use a locale param in my urls. for that i set up in the application controller something like this:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale=params[:locale]
end

def default_url_options(options={})
   { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

everything in my app is translated ok, except the devise part

am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you put the devise.ro.yml ?

Comment: the devise.ro.yml has exactly the same form as devise.en.yml, only that all strings are translated, and there's a `ro` instead of `en` at the top of the file

Comment: i fixed it. seems i had a typo somewhere in the devise.ro.yml file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suppose you do in top of you devise.ro.yml `ro` instead of `en` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to generate Devise views with: `rails generate devise:views`, then you can translate each of those to suite your locale needs.

`devise.en.yml` is only for flash messages.

Comment: i already did that, but there are things like flashes and other possible elements, that are not translated . i mean that's why the `devise.en.yml` is there, right?

Comment: You're right... Did you leave the original devise.en.yml in it's place? Triple check if your I18n.locale does change to other than :ro.

Answer (score 1):

Devise views do not use i18n by default, from now on you can use https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views to add I18n support to Devise views and mails. 
(see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1989)

Answer (score 0):

devise.ro.yml should work.

as a side-note:

I had similar problems, and used this trick to debug / find out where/what Rails is trying to lookup for translations:

http://unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/which_l10n_strings_is_rails_trying_to_lookup.html